# Getting the DB values as DAO in python ,I am using sql server as db engine

Tags: python, dao

I had a table Student with columns rollno,name,DOB,classname,gender in sqlserver I need to get those values as in the DAO format as like in java (Student.rollno="10001",...) in the python with a simple example

I just need an example that getting the values and insert into Tables in the DAO object format with an simple example